# Can I create an Automator application to start Tomcat when I need?

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, homebrew, apache

I can start Apache Tomcat (installed via HomeBrew) in Terminal using

```
$ catalina run
```

But it does not work in an Automator application Shell script using `bash`

I tried to set up a `bash` Shell script in Automator like this:

```
catalina run
```

When I run the Automator application, it won't work and shows `-: catalina: command not found`.

**What is the correct way to create an Automator application, or do I need to use AppleScript?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer the questions your asked:

- Can I create an Automator application to start and stop Tomcat when I need?

  Yes
- What is the correct way to do this, or do I need AppleScript or stuff?
- And is it possible to do both start and stop in one Automator app?
- What is the correct way to create an Automator application, or do I need to use AppleScript?

Since there is usually more then one way to accomplish something, lets refrain from using "...the correct way to..." and show you some choices.

If you simply want to be able to *toggle the state* of **Apache Tomcat**, i.e, *start* or *stop* it, then the following command line can be used in a **Automator** *Application workflow* using a **Run Shell Script** *action*:

- In **Automator**, create a new *Application workflow*.
- Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

  - *Settings*: **Shell: /bin/bash** *and* **Pass input: to stdin**

Replace the *default code* with the following line of *code*:

```
[[ $(/bin/ps aux | /usr/bin/grep [t]omcat) == "" ]] && /usr/local/bin/catalina start || /usr/local/bin/catalina stop
```

- Save the **Automator** *Application workflow*.

This command *checks* to see if **Apache Tomcat** is *running* and if *not*, then *starts* it, and if *yes*, then *stops* it. It simply *toggles the state* of **Apache Tomcat**. It's a no frills solution.

---

A more robust solution would be to use a **Run AppleScript** *action* instead.

- In **Automator**, create a new *Application workflow*.
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*.

Use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in place of the *default code*:

```
try
    set isRunning to (do shell script "/bin/ps aux | /usr/bin/grep [t]omcat")
on error number 1
    set isRunning to missing value
end try

if isRunning contains missing value then
    display dialog "                Click the Start button to start Apache Tomcat." buttons {"Cancel", "Start"} ¬
        default button 2 with title "Start Apache Tomcat"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/catalina start"
else
    display dialog "                Click the Stop button to stop Apache Tomcat." buttons {"Cancel", "Stop"} ¬
        default button 2 with title "Stop Apache Tomcat"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/catalina stop"
end if
```

- Save the **Automator** *Application workflow*.

This also could be used in an **AppleScript** *Application*, created in **Script Editor**, by itself with no need for **Automator**. In either case when run you'll be presented with one or the other *dialog boxes*.

[image: Start Apache Tomcat]
[image: Stop Apache Tomcat]

This gives you the opportunity to see whether or not it's *running* and *cancel* if you want instead.

---

**Note:** With the exception of using a `try` *statement* and an `on error number 1` *statement* there is no other *error handling* presented in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*. For additional *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add appropriate additional *error handling* for any *example code* presented.

Also, the *example code* presented herein was tested under a clean install of macOS 10.12.6 with Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode-9.1, Homebrew, JDK 9.0.1, and apache-tomcat-8.5.23.tar.gz installed. I see no reason why this would not work in macOS 10.13 as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The codes above works in 10.13! One thing I noticed is that, the dialog box does not actually take the buttons' values. (The start/stop script below the dialog box line will run whether I pressed the *start*/*stop* button or *cancel*) So I used a system notification instead: `display notification "Tomcat has started/stopped." with title "Tomcat"`.

Comment: And I loved that AppleScript is still working in 10.13, while being easy and intuitive, it also is capable of sending out notifications or popping out dialog boxes!

Comment: @jackxujh, To address what you said in your first comment... You do realize that there are two separate approaches here and both are not in the same Automator app? 1. Automator app with a Run Shell Script action and a single line of code that checks the state and toggles accordingly. 2. Automator app with a Run AppleScript action that uses the example AppleScript code. Each approach uses one of the methods but not both in the same app. Continued in next comment...

Comment: @jackxujh, If AppleScript in macOS 10.13 is functioning properly, then I find it hard to believe my example AppleScript code doesn't work as stated. Sans trapping `error "User canceled." number -128` when it occurs, there is no other code in the example AppleScript code that should get processed. As coded, an untapped `error "User canceled." number -128` should stop anything else from occurring in that example AppleScript code. I tested every possible combination while simultaneously checking in Terminal and it works for me as stated. Later I'll build out a macOS 10.13.1 system and test it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, within each run, or execution of the Automator app, it can only toggle Tomcat status once. But I found that during each, run, whether I click *cancel* or *start/stop*, it will still toggle Tomcat. This works as expected, right?

Comment: Because if I click "*cancel*" when I am presented "*Click to start*" dialog, Tomcat still starts. And the next time I run the script, I will be asked whether to "*stop Tomcat*". And the same is true vise versa. The results from `$ ps aux | grep '[t]omcat'` also confirm this odd behavior.

Comment: @jackxujh, You said "Yes, I understand that, within each run, or execution of the Automator app, it can only toggle Tomcat status once." while true, that is not at all what I'm talking about! There are two completely separate solutions in my answer, one app using Run Shell Script totally by itself and a separate app using Run AppleScript totally by itself.

Comment: @jackxujh, You said "But I found that during each, run, whether I click cancel or start/stop, it will still toggle Tomcat. This works as expected, right? ... Because if I click "cancel" when I am presented "Click to start" dialog, Tomcat still starts. And the next time I run the script, I will be asked whether to "stop Tomcat". And the same is true vise versa.", **that is not the expected behavior and not the behavior exhibited under macOS 10.12.6 and should not be the behavior under macOS 10.13!** As I previously said, "Later I'll build out a macOS 10.13.1 system and test it.".

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make myself understood that I understand you gave two elegant solutions, the first of which is a Shell script (seems compatible for most Unix-like systems, which is awesome!!), and the second is an AppleScript solution which has interaction features (Mac only). Meanwhile, it is very odd indeed that the *Cancel* button does not work as expected...

Answer (score 3):

When you run a shell command or script in Automator it is passed your system's default PATH, not the one in your bash profile. This is why bash cannot find the `catalina` command.

You should always specify the full path to the command in shell scripts. If it was installed via HomeBrew this is probably `/usr/local/bin/catalina` but you can confirm this by running `which catalina` in a terminal session.

Comment: I checked the location using `which`, and it was at the location you mentioned.